# Passing a model with two classes to view in asp.net with EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**I am new to ASP.NET and EF5.** I am doing a project in VS2012, MVC4 using EF5.

I have a class `CreateClient` where there is further two classes `Clients, FullPackages` like below:

```
public class CreateClient
{
    public Clients Clients { get; set; }
    public List<FullPackages> FullPackages { get; set; }
}
```

Class `Clients` is like this:

```
[Table("tblClients")]
public class Clients
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximum {1} characters allowed for {0} field")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Minimum {2} characters required for {0} field", MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and Class `FullPackages` is:

```
public class FullPackages
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Package Type")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; } 
    public int AllowedSMS { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time Span in Days")]
    public int? TimeSpan { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Package Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I invoked this model in my view like

```
@model SmsServer.Models.CreateClient
```

and used the `Clients` class as

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Clients.Username)
```

but i don't know to use the `List<FullPackages>` i want to use the values of list. I researched the site but didn't find any useful ideas.So Please help me.... on how to use it

**OR is there any way to do this in a more simpler way :)**

Comment: What have you tried, and why does it fail? The simplest thing to do would to stupidly iterate over the list with: `@foreach(var item in model.CreateList.FullPackages) { @Html.DisplayFor(...) }`

Comment: @Serv I tried `@foreach(IEnumerable<FullPackages> in Model.FullPackages)` but it shows this type or namespace couldnot be found

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to list them out you could do this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>TypeName</th>
    </tr>
@foreach(var package in Model.FullPackages)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@package.Id</td>
        <td>@package.TypeName</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Please note that if you want to post them back you will have to use an indexed loop instead of the foreach.